# Installed Anaconda -> strange behavior with DNF

Tags: fedora, zsh, autocomplete, dnf

I am using Fedora 26.

Since I installed Anaconda, if I type in Terminal something like

```
sudo dnf install gnome[TAB]
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'

zsh: do you wish to see all 313 possibilities (317 lines)?
```

Any idea what could have happened? It has something to do with python I guess...

UPDATE:
When I removed Anaconda from the path, i get following message:

```
➜  ~ sudo dnf install gnomezsh: sqlite3: command not found...
Install package 'sqlite' to provide command 'sqlite3'? [N/y]
```

I should also mention that I am using zsh with oh-my/zsh.

Comment: What are you trying to install actually?

Comment: It's not about what I am trying to install...

Whatever I would like to install, I get the same, strange, behavior...

Comment: It seems that you have broken `dnf`. Did you uninstall python?

Comment: There is an [old question](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/76711/yumdnf-and-python-all-messed-up/#) with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `zsh`. Change the instances of python2 and python3 in `/usr/share/zsh/5.*your_version*/functions/_dnf` to `/usr/bin/python2`and `/usr/bin/python3` respectively.

This solved my problem. Big thanks to https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/886

Comment: The problem appears while interacting with `zsh`'s internal auto-complete function for commandline arguments.  It calls a command in order to complete/guess what you are trying to write, and it is this auto-completion (which can be configured to be an external command) fails.